# Can Origin headers be sent with get variables or the whole url?

Tags: same-origin-policy, cors

An application I'm working on responds to a wildcard Origin header by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `subdomain.app.com` if ending with `.app.com`.

However, if I append `.app.com` to a GET variable, as below:

`Origin: example.com?q=.app.com`

it responds with the following:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com?q=.app.com`

This is vulnerable if browsers can be configured to pass the GET variable, or entire url.

I'm wondering if any browsers send the `Origin` header along with the entire url, or if JavaScript can be configured to allow this. From my testing Chrome / Firefox set the Origin header to the tld only, does anyone know if this configuration is vulnerable?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244526/is-it-possible-for-origin-header-to-have-alphaebtical-port-or-parameters-in-real

Answer (score 1):

Origin is a [Forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), and standards compliant user agent should only send the domain name in the origin header. They cannot be modified programmatically in standards compliant browsers. Note that user agents that doesn't try to be standards compliant, such as curl, or very old browsers before the specification was written, may not enforce this restriction.

Comment: Seems that browsers enforce: `Origin: <scheme> "://" <host> [ ":" <port> ]`, so I guess the answer to my question is it isn't vulnerable.