# Can the Origin header have alphabetical port or parameters in a real-life scenario?

Tags: web-application, cors, same-origin-policy, header

I'm testing this application which is properly validating origin header on the sever side. However, if I add any domain and the expect domain as port, application still consider this valid.

`Origin: https://random-domain.com:expected-domain.com`

This is also valid.

`Origin: https://random-domain.com?expected.domain.com`

I'm doing all this from my intercepting proxy but in real world origin header can't have parameters, fragments or alphabetical ports (numeric ports are possible though)

Is there a solution for this?  I'm looking for a solution to bypass this and send an arbitrary origin header value and still get successful response.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is there a solution for what? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear, just updated the post. I'm looking for a solution to bypass this and submit an arbitrary origin header value and still get successful request.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering whether the behaviour you described can be abused, I can think of at least one exploit ([described by James Kettle](https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties), from PortSwigger) that can lead to the equivalent of stored XSS, but only under certain conditions:

1. The value of the `Origin` request header gets reflected verbatim in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header can have security implications.
2. There is some Web caching but no `Vary: Origin` in responses.

You could then craft a request with a malicious `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value containing a carriage return,

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Origin: z[0x0d]Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-7
```

which would result in a header injection in some browsers (IE),

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: z
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-7
```

That malicious response would get cached on the server side and delivered to subsequent visitors.